# Can overdetermined systems have infinitely many solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can overdeterminend systems have infinitely many solutions? IF so, can someone point me to an example of one?

Comment: Dimension 2: $y=1,2y=2,3y=3$

Comment: @Ian The latter is in fact the standard definition - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system.

Comment: ...Odd, I seem to recall never learning a term for "more equations than variables"...but this usage does seem to match up with Strang (the one linear algebra text I have immediate access to).

Comment: @Ian. I think the usual terminology is: "overdetermined" means more equations than variables; "inconsistent" means contradictory equations and hence no solutions.

Answer (score 5):

A system with more equations than variables is called overdetermined. It can be either consistent or inconsistent. If one or more equations are a linear combination of the other, you can always obtain a consistent system.
For example, $$x+2y=4$$$$3x+6y=12$$$$5x+10y=20$$$$......$$

Answer (score 4):

Sure - $\{0x+y=0, 0x+y=0, 0x+y=0\}$.

Or in one variable: $\{0x=0, 0x=0\}$.

Comment: That illustrates why the definition of "overdetermined" is so dissatisfying. It should have to do with the dimension of the affine solution space, not with whether the $A$ matrix in $A x = b$ is fat or thin.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I don't really agree. We have a word for when the solution space is empty - "inconsistent." I think overdetermined systems are worth naming.

Comment: One could use the words "inconsistent", "determined" and "underdetermined". You gave an example of a "thin & underdetermined" system.